# AngularJs - how to cancel route change event

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am using following code to stop routing on navigation warning pop

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
        if (!$window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this view?')) {

            event.preventDefault();
        }
})
```

But event.preventDefault() is not working for me. On the cancel button of navigation popup is still routing me to the new URL . Please help me out

Comment: provide a plunker with the issue

Comment: I've high doubt about the if-statement validation...

Comment: In other case $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")
        if (!answer) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        })
above code is also not working